# error with if statement

Tags: php

hi im using a script to include scripts based in $_GET but im getting a erorr

```
<?php
$config = array(
'videos' => 'dynapage/scripts/videos.php',
'testbed' => 'dynapage/scripts/testbed.php'
);

if(isset($config[$_GET['page']])) {
     include($config[$_GET['page']]);
}
else {
include("home.php");
}
?>
```

im getting the following error

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in D:\webdesign\webserver\root\dynapage\scripts\pagecheck.php on line 7
```

any help much apreciated

Comment: First of all check if `$_GET['page']` is set at all, then you can continue.

Comment: Just including something you get from somewhere is _highly_ dangerous!

Comment: Btw: it's not an error, it's a notice. Sounds like nitpicking, but there is a difference: this is just a notice that it isn't set, but forgiving as PHP is, it will continue (with the value "false"). Ofcourse, you don't want these notices because they could be a sign of something bad, but be aware of the different error-levels.

Comment: @kingCrunch: there is a whitelist per that `$config` array, so no real problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && isset($config[$_GET['page']])) {
     include($config[$_GET['page']]);
}
```

In `if` condition, conditions are checked from first to last, in sequence, in the above case, earlier you were requesting `$_GET['page']]` which checking is that is Available or not, Putting the `isset($_GET['page']])` does this job, if not set, further conditions will not be checked.

Comment: works great thanks what was the problem with the code i was using

Comment: The order of the operands is important here, might be good to point that out.

Comment: @rees92 The reason is that `$_GET['page']` (ie. the url doesn't contain something like: ?page=10) isn't set when you're doing your check against `$config[$_GET['page']]` so PHP tells you this so that you won't just dismiss it.

Answer (score 1):

You could change it to:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && isset($config[$_GET['page']])) {
     include($config[$_GET['page']]);
}
```